# How to send two radio buttons values to controller in mvc4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

When I create new product, I need to define it is local or not. Product model has **IsLocal** property in boolean type.

Here is view:

```
<form action="/Product/Create" method="post" id="Product_Form">
        <div>
            <label>Local</label>
            <input type="radio" name="IsLocal" id="IsLocal" value="yes" checked="checked" tabindex="10" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Not local</label>
            <input type="radio" name="IsLocal" value="no" tabindex="11" />
        </div>

      <div id="yes">
          //some fields looks when product is local.
        </div>
        ...
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="large" tabindex="17" />
 </form>
```

Firstly, **Local** radiobutton is checked. When I check **Not local**, some fields hide with this code.

```
<script>
      $("input:radio[name='IsLocal']").click(function () {
      $('#yes').hide();
      $('#' + $("input:radio[name='IsLocal']:checked").val()).show(); });
</script>
```

But, I should send values to controller with jquery function which i found.

```
jQuery.post('/Product/Create', {
                    Name: jQuery('#Name').val(),
                    IsLocal: jQuery('#IsLocal').val(),
                    ImagePath: jQuery('#ImagePath').val(),
                    CategoryId: jQuery('#CategoryId').val(),
                    Price: jQuery('#Price').val(),
                    ............................ 
                    formname: 'Product_Form',
                    formtype: 'ProductF'
}
```

**Problem is that, IsLocal is always false.** But, other field's values goes to controller correctly. How should I do that, to send **IsLocal** value depending on its checking?
(Sorry for bad English)

**Edit:**

I changed `<input>` with `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` :

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsLocal, true, new { id = "IsLocal_true", value = "yes", Checked = "checked" })

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsLocal, false, new { id = "IsLocal_false", value = "no" })
```

`IsLocal` works, but now hiding of panel doesnt work.
Now, How must I change this script? To hide and show `<div id="yes">` tag.

```
<script>
      $("input:radio[name='IsLocal']").click(function () {
      $('#yes').hide();
      $('#' + $("input:radio[name='IsLocal']:checked").val()).show(); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: jQuery('#IsLocal').is(":checked")

```
jQuery.post('/Product/Create', {
                    Name: jQuery('#Name').val(),
                    IsLocal: jQuery('#IsLocal').is(":checked"),
                    ImagePath: jQuery('#ImagePath').val(),
                    CategoryId: jQuery('#CategoryId').val(),
                    Price: jQuery('#Price').val(),
                    ............................ 
                    formname: 'Product_Form',
                    formtype: 'ProductF'
}
```

**For Your Edit**

See demo here http://jsfiddle.net/43GsG/4/

HTML:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsLocal, true, new { name = "IsLocal", id = "IsLocal_true", value = "yes", Checked = "checked" })

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsLocal, false, new { name = "IsLocal", id = "IsLocal_false", value = "no" })
```

JS:

```
$("input[name=IsLocal]").click(function () {
    if($('#IsLocal_true').is(":checked")){
      $('#yes').show();
    }
    else {
      $('#yes').hide();
    }
  });
```

Comment: I tested and it worked. I made an example for you here http://jsfiddle.net/43GsG/1/

Comment: thanks for it. You are right. but, I cannot understand, why it does not work in my project..

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value of the select radio button, it is better to do it in following way.

> jQuery('input:radio[name=IsLocal]:checked').val();

Comment: I think there is some problem with your code. Because the code line which I have posted is not returning some bool value but the value of the radiobox selected.

Comment: **You missed name attribute. Check following code.**



`@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsLocal, true, new { id = "IsLocal_true", name="IsLocal",value = "yes", Checked = "checked" })`




`@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsLocal, false, new { id = "IsLocal_false", name="IsLocal", value = "no" })`

Comment: Now when check second radiobutton, it works, hiding, but, not showing again, when check first radiobutton

Comment: **Update JS** `$("input[name=IsLocal]").click(function () {
    if($('#IsLocal_true').is(":checked")){
      $('#yes').show();
    }
    else {
      $('#yes').hide();
    }
  });`

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
  jQuery('#IsLocal').attr('checked');
```